# IOS/Core-Data: add many to many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data

In the detail page for an item, my app lets users tag the item from a list of previously created tags.  Items and tags are each an entity in Core Data and are connected via a many-to-many relationship.

When the user selects the tag in the item detail page, I am trying to create the relationship in Core Data as follows:

```
_selectedTag.item=self.item; // where self.item is the item being viewed.
```

While there is only one item being viewed, self.item, the relationship is many to many meaning an item can have more than one tag and tags can be assigned to more than one item.

Accordingly, the above line throws a warning: Incompatible pointer types assigning to NSSet from items and when you run the app it crashes.

Can anyone suggest the proper way to set this relationship.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set up a many-to-many relationship, CoreData generates the methods you need to add the links between the two entities involved in the files it generates.  For example, for an entity Track that I use I have a many-to-many relationship with the entity Contact thats named includesContact in the Track record. Based on this, CoreData generates the following method hooks in the file Track+CoreDataProperties.swift:

```
// MARK: Generated accessors for includesContact
extension Track {

    @objc(addIncludesContactObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToIncludesContact(_ value: Contact)

    @objc(removeIncludesContactObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromIncludesContact(_ value: Contact)

    @objc(addIncludesContact:)
    @NSManaged public func addToIncludesContact(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeIncludesContact:)
   @NSManaged public func removeFromIncludesContact(_ values: NSSet)

}
```

It generates the reverse method hooks in the file for the Contact entity.

When I need to add a single Contact to the includesContact relationship, I use addIncludesContact with a single Contact argument.  Alternatively, I use the NSSet version to add relationships for multiple Contacts.

For example, to add a single Contact, myContact, to a new Track called newRecord, this works as follows:

```
    newRecord.addToIncludesContact(myContact)
```

For multiple Contacts stored in the array selectedContacts, it goes as follows:

```
    newRecord.addToIncludesContact(selectedContacts as NSSet)
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know Swift.  Do you know if there is any equivalent in Objective-C?

Comment: Ok.  Found the objective-c equivalent accessors but what got it to work was placing the selectedTag which was an object in an array into an NSSet as follows.   _selectedTagInSet = [NSSet setWithObjects:_selectedTag, nil];Once I did that, core data allowed me to set the relationship with self.item.tag = _selectedTagInSet;
.

Comment: Glad that it worked out - sorry, never picked up ObjC